# Unable to install Realtek High Definition Audio driver - "No Audio Output Device is installed."

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, realtek-hd-audio

Today my partner's Windows 10 Lenovo Yoga 720-13IKB decided it no longer wanted to produce any audio. It's coming up with "No Audio Output Device is installed.".

[Screenshot of the error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3A1Rq.png)

The troubleshooter was no help. So I thought okay, I'll uninstall the Realtek High Definition Audio Driver, restart the laptop, and reinstall.

However, the driver now seems permanently gone. I've navigated to the Lenovo site, redownloaded the driver, and attempted to install it. The Realtek Audio Driver Setup Wizard runs with no issues.

[Completed Realtek Audio Driver Setup Wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooCeM.png)

But when I launch Realtek Audio, it opens the Device Driver Installation Wizard which seems to show a series of successes and a single failure for the driver.

[This image shows the results.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t18jO.png)

All the driver names are identical. There's 3 "ready to use rows", 1 "Install Failed" row, and 4 "Not needed" rows. I still haven't managed to get the driver back in the list of drivers in Device Manager and I'm at a loss of what else to try at this point. The laptop has been restarted multiple times. Is there anything I can do to get audio back on this laptop?

My Googling seems to reveal this is a really common challenge but what I've read has boiled down to "if uninstalling and reinstalling the driver doesn't work then the hard drive is busted".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "if uninstalling and reinstalling the driver doesn't work then the
> hard drive is busted".

Just as likely (possibly more so), the Audio hardware has failed.

I suggest you get the machine serviced either by contacting Lenovo Support or taking it to a local shop to get an assessment and possibly a repair.

It may be (because laptop Audio is built into the motherboard, possibly more economical to replace the computer. A local shop can help with the repair or replace issue.

This is not ((95%+) a software issue.

Comment: Thanks John, this pretty much aligns with my fears. I'm used to driver issues normally being pretty simple, albeit frustrating, to fix so I was caught off guard by the fact that this is a sign that the hardware is on its way out and was hoping that I was just simply missing something.